# simulate many to many relation using C structures

Tags: c, data-structures

This is an interview problem. We have to design an employee database with basic fields - emp_id, emp_name.

But, we need to maintain hierarchy too. so that we can support queries like :

- given an emp_id/emp_name, find out the reporting manager.
- list down all the employees reporting to a particular manager.

The question is how to implement this many-to-many relation using data-structures in C. In SQL, we can maintain this easily using a separate table where we have mapping of employee's emp_id Vs. its manager's emp_id.

I was thinking in terms of using a hash table with chaining to represent the same.

Edit: An employee can have multiple managers in the sense that they have different managers at different levels of hierarchy. e.g. reporting manager, senior manager etc.

Comment: Seems more like a many-to-one problem: Many employees to one manager. And it's easy to solve: If you have a collection of employees it's easy to search that one to find all that have a specific manager.

Comment: so it's a directed graph, isn't it?

Comment: Your "multiple managers" is not really many-to-many, it's just a hierarchy. You get the employee's manager, then you get his manager, and so on up the tree.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yes you are right, edited the question as to why i think its a many to many relationship.

Comment: And if you want to get everyone below a senior manager, you use a recursive search: get his direct reports, recurse into each of them to get their direct reports, and so on.

Comment: Anyway, what's your question about this? You need to post your code and explain the problem you're having with it, StackOverflow is not intended for open-ended design discussion.

Comment: My question is - what DS we can use it to store in C. I was thinking of using Hash table with chaining.

Comment: You can use any data structure that stores pairs `(employee's emp_id, manager's emp_id)` and allows searching by either field. Normally that would mean you maintain two separate search structures, one for each field you want to search by, that store your pairs *by reference*. Hash table with chaining is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a structure similar to the following?

```
typedef struct NODE_S
   {
   /* Parent node (manager).  Many (employees) to one (manager) */
   struct NODE_S *parent; 

   /* Peer-level employees. */
   struct NODE_S *prev;    /* Previous peer employee */
   struct NODE_S *next;    /* Next peer employee */

   /* Employees who report to this (manager) node. :: One (manager) to many (employees) */
   struct NODE_S *head;    /* First reporting employee. */
   struct NODE_S *tail;    /* Last reporting employee. */

   /* Employee data. */
   unsigned int  id;
   char         *name;
   char         *title;
   } NODE_T;
```

Example test code for this structure can be found [here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/24476168_simulate-many-to-many-relation-using-c-structures.c).

Comment: thanks for sharing this. Only issue i think will be that every structure will have head and tail pointers, although there will be very few managers and many employees , so it might lead to a lot of wastage of space IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally used:

```
typedef struct emp_data_s{
    char *name;
    char *designation;
    unsigned long salary;
} emp_data_t, *pemp_data_t;

typedef struct emp_s{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int manager;
    pemp_data_t data;
    struct emp_s *next;
    struct emp_s *firstchild;
    struct emp_s *nextchild;
} emp_t, *pemp_t;
```